# FTDI code 10 - what can I do to resolve problem?

Tags: usb, ftdi, pc

I am using the FT230X as a USART to USB interface on my boards. The first few work OK but then with the last one I get a Code 10 (cannot start) on my PC. It works fine on another PC when tried.

I have read [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_107_AdvancedDriverOptions_AN_000073.pdf), and also updated, uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers. Nothing has been of any use.

Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?

Comment: not really an ee issue as a card works on other pc's. Code10 from an ftdi FTD2XX point of view is FAILED_TO_WRITE_DEVICE0

Comment: If I asked this question in a PC oriented group the chances of anyone having any knowledge of the FTDI chips is approximately zero

Comment: Isn't that the same error you get with many of those fake cp210x since they updated the drivers? - Check and see if you have the exact same driver version on both PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples! As it turned out... Use a shorter cable. I was using a 3m length and have replaced it with a 1.5m. There are presumably loading or termination issues although my board only takes 280mA and I followed FTDI guidelines for layout etc.

Comment: by any chance do you have a capacitor from the 0V to the shield on your card (with maybe a parallel 1MR) as per the appnotes?  "We" have found that to be a serious issue and have replaced that RC parallel combination with a 0R